# Javascript load content into Div problems

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to on the click of a link display a different page inside a box using jquery (.load). I'm new to programming and web design so please make answers as simple as possible.

Here is my index.html code

```
<nav id="navBar">
    <a href="#" onclick="homeLoad()" class="navLink">Home</a>          
    <a href="#" onclick="aboutLoad()" class="navLink">About</a>            
    <a href="#" onclick="contactLoad()" class="navLink">Contact</a>  
    <a href="#" onclick="shopLoad()" class="navLink">Shop</a> 
</nav>
<div id="loadZone"></div>
```

and my JavaScript

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#loadZone").load("homeLoad.html");
});
function homeLoad() {
    $('#loadZone').load('homeLoad.html');
}

function aboutLoad() {
    $('#loadZone').load('aboutLoad.html');
}
```

loading the home page (homeLoad.html) works fine 
when I repeatedly spam the link for about you can occasionally see the content of aboutLoad.html

Any help appreciated
Thanks

Comment: I didn't really understand the problem to be honest.

Comment: The aboutLoad does't display Thanks anyway

Comment: You want to da that: on click at About - die homeLoad.html should disappear and aboutLoad should appear?

Comment: Since you're new to programming, here's a few tips that will help you along the way: 1) get away from DOM-zero event binding, which is to say, don't use `onclick=` attributes in your HTML. Separate your HTML, CSS and JS. Look into jQuery's `on()` method for better event handling. Secondly, look in the console (CTRL+SHIFT+I, if you're on Windows) when you click the about link. Any error? If not, do the same but this time look in the network tab. Is the page loaded, and is the response what you expect?

Comment: The network tab is scrolling between jquery and homeLoad.html. The console says "Synchronous XMLHttpRequest on the main thread is deprecated because of its detrimental effects to the end user's experience. For more help http://xhr.spec.whatwg.org/ jquery.min.js:5:0"

Comment: @Utkanos using on() makes the content of loadZone rapidly change for 5 seconds then settle on the homeLoad content

Comment: Why would you this if you have access to all the HTML files?

Comment: so users don't have to reload the page

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A simpler method might be to store the urls as data attributes on the links, then when the user clicks a link get the stored url and load it. To load the initial content, trigger a click on it's link on load. Something like this would work:

[Here is a working Demo](http://dodsoftware.com/sotests/loadtest/#)

```
<nav id="navBar">
    <a href="#" data-url="home.html" class="navLink">Home</a>          
    <a href="#" data-url="about.html" class="navLink">About</a>            
    <a href="#" data-url="contact.html" class="navLink">Contact</a>  
    <a href="#" data-url="shop.html" class="navLink">Shop</a> 
</nav>
<div id="loadZone"></div>


<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.navLink').click(function(e){
        e.preventDefault;
        $('#loadZone').load($(this).data('url'));
    });
    $('.navLink:eq(0)').click();
});
</script>
```